# Whether my answer is correct for this question? provide me with some advise

Tags: proof-verification, cryptography

This is a 3-person encryption scheme based on RSA. One manager(can be trusted in this case) generates two large primes $p$ and $q$, calculates both $n$ and $\phi(n)$. The manager also chooses $k_1$, $k_2$ and $k_3$ such that $\gcd(k_i, n) = 1$ and $k_1k_2k_3 \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$. Keys are securely distributed to three others as follows:

A: 
 $\langle n, k_1, k_2 \rangle$

B:
$\langle n, k_2, k_3 \rangle$

C:
$\langle n, k_3, k_1 \rangle$

Question: A has a message $M_1$ for B. Give the encryption function for A as well as the decryption function for B, so that the message won’t be seen by anyone else.

My answer:
Given that $k_1$, $k_2$, and $k_3$ are such that $\gcd(k_i, n) = 1$ and that $k_1k_2k_3 \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$.
Since , A had a message for B.                                                 Encryption formula for A: $C_1 = M_1^{k_1} \pmod{n}$

Decryption formula for B: $M_1 = C_1^{k_2k_3} \pmod{n}$

Because $k_1k_2k_3 \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$, $M_1^{k_1k_2k_3} \equiv M_1 \pmod{n}$. Thus, $C_1^{k_2k_3} \pmod{n} = M_1^{k_1k_2k_3} \pmod{n}$ $= M_1$.

Answer (score 1):

It looks OK. Can you also argue why in this message from A to B, C cannot eavesdrop? and nor can anyone not A,B or C?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I can prove it. But I still have two questions.                                                          1. what does 'gcd(,)=1' mean? in this question, I didn't use it                             2. do I need to proved GCD(k1, ()) = 1 and the inverse of k1 is k2k3? because in RSA, GCD(e, ()) =1 and the inverse of e is d.

Comment: $\gcd(k_1,\phi(n))$ is necessary for security and to find $k_2k3$. You must have some numbertheory lemma in your text that shows that $m = 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$ implies that $x^{m} = 1 \pmod{n}$, right?